# Probability of distinguishing between monitoring and query request in multiple intervals

Tags: probability

In our work, we distribute a day in `I` intervals. In each interval, there is one monitoring request and in `x` random intervals there is a query request. To summarize, there are I intervals in total. `x` out of `I` intervals would have monitoring + query requests, rest of intervals have only monitoring requests.

I am trying to find the probability for 3 events, and the following are the answers I get:

1. find at least one query request accurately = (x/I) *0.5
2. find one specific query request accurately = (1/I) *0.5
3. find all query request accurately = 0.5^I * 0.5^x

Is it correct or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't really follow the question. What does it mean to find a query request accurately? What are we querying?

Answer (score 1):

We need to make many assumptions such as each intervals are equally likely to be selected and we select $m$ intervals without repetitions. I also assume $m \le I$.

Note that $0.5$ is not special at all.

- The complement of at least one is none is we find no query requests accurately.

$$1-\prod_{i=1}^m \frac{(I-x)-(i-1)}{I-(i-1)}$$

- To find one specific query accurately, we need to select the slot where the success happened.

$$m\cdot \left(\frac1I \right)$$

- To find all queries, clearly, we need $x \le m \le I$, we choose the slots to place those query slots:

$$\binom{m}{x}\left(\prod_{i=1}^x\frac{x-(i-1)}{I-(i-1)} \right)$$